# Looking to get LocalStorage value that changes constantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

Hope I can explain my problem in a way that makes sense.

I'm changing CSS themes on a button click, and when the button of a specific theme is clicked, it saves that classname to the LocalStorage, but because the LocalStorage key and value are constantly changing I just want to call whatever is set in localstorage after the click, rather than a specific value. I'm using jQuery for the button clicks, and i've included my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dark').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-dark');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme-dark', ['theme-dark']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme-dark');
    });

    $('#light').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-light');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme-light', ['theme-light']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme-dark');
    });

    $('#beaker').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-beaker');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme-beaker', ['theme-beaker']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme-dark');
    });

    $('#outrun').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-outrun');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme-outrun', ['theme-outrun']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme-dark');
    });

    var localItem = localStorage.getItem('theme-outrun');

    $('body').addClass(localItem);

});
```

Comment: use one key name rather than multiple

Comment: You absolute Legend, thats it working, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a single key to set the different themes in the local storage

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dark').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-dark');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme', ['theme-dark']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme');
    });

    $('#light').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-light');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme', ['theme-light']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme');
    });

    $('#beaker').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-beaker');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme', ['theme-beaker']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme');
    });

    $('#outrun').click(function(){
        $('#app-root').removeClass();
        $('#app-root').addClass('theme-outrun');
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('theme', ['theme-outrun']);
        localStorage.getItem('theme');
    });

    var localItem = localStorage.getItem('theme');

    $('body').addClass(localItem);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same key for all the localstorage.setItem and getItem

or

at the end do this

```
var localItem  = localStorage.getItem(Object.keys(localStorage)[0])

$('body').addClass(localItem);
```

Comment: Brrr, `Object.keys(localStorage)[0]`...  Storage object has a [`key()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key) method, use it instead please.